# Hibernate + Spring + JUnit Tests

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, junit

In my project I have an service (marked as @Transactional), containing method which **reads a record from DB into an entity and updates it with some data**.
It was working fine until I decided to write some JUnit tests..

Here is the problem.. I am extending the test class with **AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests** - need it for a rollback after test. Also in the test method I am creating new entity, and save it to the DB. Than I am invoking my service's method which should update the entity. After invoking the method I see *Object already associated with session* in the logs, so it is not updated and the test fails.

I know in the time when the service tries to update entity, it has two objects with same ID etc., but **what can I do in such situation?** Using the merge in the service is not an option I think...

Greetings,
M.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. As always just after asking I figured out an answer...

In the test method I added invoking the **flush and the clear of current session**, after that everything is going fine.